# Convert a JSON file to CSV or XLS (Excel) format

Tags: conversion, csv, json

I have a number of JSON files which my old charting system will not accept as a data format for import.  Is there an easy way to convert these to CSV or XLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are small enough, there are a few online JSON to CSV converters you can use such as:

[json-csv.com](https://json-csv.com).

Comment: What if the file is larger? i have an 8mb file and i need to convert it to csv, is there any tool for large files?

Answer (score 1):

This service translates large json files to csv for free. I checked files of 100 megabytes.
http://json-csv-xls.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool: [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter-online.com) 
Hope this help!

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I had a pretty large json (~100M) and  used this app from windows store  to convert it into csv -  https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NXC23M6FRQJ